# How do I list the tag groups that are actually in use?

Tags: templating, navigation, tags, group

I'm developing a masonry photo gallery with some filters (colors, style, manufacturer, etc) and I want to use tags to filter them by. I need some navigation which should look like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Tag Group 1
        <ul>
            <li>Tag 1</li>
            <li>Tag 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Tag Group 2
        <ul>
            <li>Tag 3</li>
            <li>tag 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I read this article https://craftcms.com/support/active-tags but I can't figure out how to get all group tags and for them all the tags that are actualy in use. I think i should use

```
{% for tag in craft.tags.group('blogTags') %}
```

but I want to get all the group handles in a loop dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`group`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters#group) filter to group your tags by tag groups:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('gallery').limit(null) %}

<ul>

    {# Get all the tags related to our gallery entries and group them by tag group #}
    {% set allGalleryTags = craft.tags.relatedTo(entries)|group('group') %}

    {# Loop the tag groups #}
    {% for tagGroup, tagsInGroup in allGalleryTags %}

        <li>
            <h2>{{ tagGroup }}</h2>
            <ul>

                {# Loop the tags of this group #}
                {% for tag in tagsInGroup %}
                    <li>{{ tag.name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}

            </ul>
        </li>

    {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much dude. It works flawless.

Comment: Glad to help, @Cipick. If you have lots of tags you could further group them by the first letter: `{% for letter, tagByLetter in tagsInGroup|group('name|slice(0, 1)') %}`.